# REACT ERROR : Why get error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef') TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got this error whike trying to link some pages to my App.js page
This is the error:

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
> at Object.useRef

And here is my code in App.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Home } from './Pages/Home';
import { About } from './Pages/About';
import { Contact } from './Pages/Contact'


function App() {

// ONE :

return <>
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />}  />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />}  />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
</>
}
export default App;
```

and this is the code in my Home page(All those two pages are the same):

```
export const Home = () =>{
    return(
        <div>This is Home page</div>
    )
}
```

All Home, About and contact pages are in a folder which I named "Pages" in src folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same quesion bro, I solved it by installing react-router-dom. You can check whether you have successfully installed react-router-dom by running this commend : **npm list react-router-dom**, if it turns out **(empty)**, that means you need to install react-router-dom by running this commend **npm install react-router-dom** and restart your react app, good luck!